# About changing the playground size of the Veins

Tags: omnet++

How to reduce the playground size as well as how to start the vehicles from the middle of the road. Where and which file should I have change?

Answer (score 1):

In Veins, node mobility of cars is entirely managed by SUMO. Whenever a new car starts in the SUMO simulation, a node is created in OMNeT++. Whenever (and wherever) the car moves in SUMO, it is moved in OMNeT++. If you want to change how the nodes (that represent cars) move, just change the SUMO simulation (by creating new routes or an entirely new network).

If you want to know more about how to create and change SUMO simulations, you can find in-depth information in the SUMO manual.

Comment: Is it possible to change the omnet.ini scenario from :  *.playgroundSizeX = 2500m
*.playgroundSizeY = 2500m
 to *.playgroundSizeX = 1000m
*.playgroundSizeY = 1000m  with minimal change in the existing codes.

Comment: @Zecar - Yes, it's possible but make sure the nodes don't move out of the playground. You will be notified of this situation by an appropriate message during the simulation.